# $.ajax() not working in firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, google-chrome, jquery

A jQuery .ajax() call of mine is not working in firefox but it is working in Chrome. Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/forms/remove_photo/' + temp,
        complete: function() {
            $('#photo').remove();
        }
    });
```

However, in firefox '/forms/remove_photo/' (which is a php function) is not being called, but the complete function is still executing. There are no parseErrors or syntax errors showing up in firebug. In chrome the function is being called and running successfully.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you clear the browser cache and try ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `success` instead of `complete`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/forms/remove_photo/' + temp,

  success: function (data) {
    $('#photo').remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    cache: 'false', // just to clear your cache
    url: '/forms/remove_photo/' + temp,
    success: function() {  // this may be more appropriate
        $('#photo').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with `$.ajax` in firefox but it works like a charm in chrome, what happens it's that since chrome handles javascript and ajax faster, firefox seems to get left behind making you scratch your head, what you can do it's to use [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) That way you can handle ajax with more control, here is an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/forms/remove_photo/' + temp        
}).done(function(){
    $('#photo').remove();
});
```

I suggest you do some research to the Deferreds object as it will help you a lot

Comment: Deffereds are for organising callback queus, speed is more down to server response time than how quickly browsers handle it. Deferreds are great, but not for the reasons in your answer.

Comment: Yeah but just last week i was creating a web application that runned on a localhost server and firefox was giving me trouble, so i worked it all out with Deferreds